# Telerik Kendo Ui Grid RuntimeBinderException

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

Our problem is that the object-bound Kendo grid throws a `RuntimeBinderException` with message:

`"object does not include the following definition: '<property name>' " during
initialization. (Exception rised in GridForeignKeyColumn.cs line 83)`

This occurs in case when:

- grid is in (cell) edit mode
- foreign key columns present.

There is a conditional statement just before the faulting line,
checking that the model type is a `DataRow`, so I've tried to bind with
`DataTable`, `DataRow` too (it would be ok for us) but result was
the same.

If I change the grid's binding from object to concrete type, everything
is perfect.

We would like to:

- Keep the grid object-bound
- Keep cell edit bode too.

Is this possible?

In the [example](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/binding-to-datatable-0191a594e359), If I change the edit mode from popup to cell, I run into the same issue.

Framework version we use: Kendo UI v2015.1.408